# Studying the convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't find a way to know the convergence of this series :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+3^nn}$$

I tried to resolve this limit :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+3^nn}}$$

but it was not that simple to resolve.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Break it up into two subseries, and use squeezing for each.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $\dfrac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+3^n} < \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+3^nn}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big({\frac{3^n-2^n}{4^n+3^nn}}\Big)^{\frac1n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{3^n}{4^n}\frac{1-(\frac23)^n}{1+(\frac34)^nn}\Big)^{\frac1n}\\
&=\frac34\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\frac{1-(\frac23)^n}{1+(\frac34)^nn}\Big)^{\frac1n}\\
&=\frac34<1.
\end{align}